# Why are we using the same arbitrary constant while solving this first order higher degree differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

Consider the differential equation,

$$p^2 - (\frac{x}{y} - \frac{y}{x})p - 1 = 0, p = y'$$

This problem can be tackled by solving the quadratic in $p$. I found out that $p=\frac{x}{y},  \frac{-y}{x}.$

Therefore,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-y}{x} \implies xy = c \tag{1}\label{eq1}$

Or, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y} \implies x^2-y^2 = c \tag{2}\label{eq2}$

Combining, we can write, $(xy - c)(x^2-y^2 - c) = 0$, which is the General Solution.

But I don't understand why we used the same arbitrary constant $c$ in both equations — $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\eqref{eq2}$? Shouldn't it be two different arbitrary constants?

Comment: Why didn't you use different constants in your solution?

Comment: @Gonçalo It was the solution given in my textbook. There was no explanation as to why two different constants weren't used.

Answer (score 3):

There are two separate one-parameter families of solutions: $xy = c$ and $x^2 - y^2 = c$.  Combining them as $(xy-c)(x^2-y^2-c)$ is just obfuscation.  And there is no reason for the constants $c$ to be the same: there is no connection between them.

Comment: I see. So even if I had written the solutions as $xy = c$ and $x^2-y^2 = k$, it wouldn't be wrong, right?